# Solve sigma example

Tags: math

I have a sigma example:

[image: Sigma Example]

And I don't have any idea how to solve it. Can you help me with the code, please?

(Code pascal, java or c++)

Comment: If you don't understand the mathematical syntax, you're on the wrong site to be asking about that. If you do understand the syntax, what specific problem are you having converting this to code? What language are you trying to write this code in?

Comment: C++ or Java. It doesn't matter

Comment: These are summations.  You'll do the inner one 30 times for each of the 20 outer sums.

Comment: If you understand what the math is, but don't know how to code it, then you're going to have to start by learning the basics of the language you'll use. This isn't a place to have others do your homework. If you try something, feel free to bring it on here for help on where you went wrong. You'll want to look into "for".

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the inner term, you get `m^3 - 3m^2n + 3mn^2 - n^3`, which yields a double summation of `m^5`, `-3m^4n`, `3m^3n^2` and `-m^2n^3`. These summations are separable, meaning that they are the product of a sum on `m` of a power of `m` and a sum on `n` of a power of `n`.

You can evaluate these sums by means of the [Faulhaber formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) up to degree five, which are polynomial expressions. Evaluate them by [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

```
int  F1(int n) { return (n + 1) * n / 2; }
int  F2(int n) { return ((2 * n + 3) * n + 1) * n / 6; }
int  F3(int n) { return ((n + 2) * n + 1) * n * n / 4; }
...

int S= F5(20) * 30 - 3 * F4(20) * F1(30) + 3 * F3(20) * F2(30) - F2(20) * F3(30);
```

---

Using the obvious method of summation, the inner loop will evaluate `30` cubes of a difference, for a total of `60` additions and `60` multiplications, and the outer loop will repeat this `20` times, with extra multiplications and additions, for a total of `1220 +` and `1240 *`.

Compare to the above method, performing `18 +`, `30 *` and `7` divisions in total (independently of the values of `m` and `n`).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this:
`int main() {`
 int result = 0;

 for (int m=1; m <= 20; m++) {
  int temp = 0;

  for (int n=1; n <= 30; n++) {
   temp += pow((m - n), 3);
  }

  result += pow(m, 2) * temp;
 }

 cout << result;

 return 0;
}`

Comment: @VENTO: thank you for informing me that you disregarded my answer.